# Is there a way to loop through a sub section of a list in Python

Tags: python, loops, list

So for a list that has 1000 elements, I want to loop from 400 to 500. How do you do it?

I don't see a way by using the for each and for range techniques.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
for x in thousand[400:500]:
    pass
```

If you are working with an iterable instead of a list, you should use [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools):

```
import itertools
for x in itertools.islice(thousand, 400, 500):
    pass
```

If you need to loop over `thousand[500]`, then use 501 as the latter index. This will work even if `thousand[501]` is not a valid index.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `alist[istart:iend]` creates a completely new list with a shallow copy of all elements from `alist` between `istart` and `iend` indices. It is a O(iend-istart) operation.

Answer (score 7):

```
for element in allElements[400:501]:
     # do something
```

These are [slices](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#id8) and generate a sublist of the whole list. They are one of the main elements of Python.

Comment: Thanks. So this will include both 400th and 500th elements?

Comment: Only if the upper bound is 501.

Answer (score 2):

Using

```
for element in allElements[400:501]:
    doSomething(element)
```

makes Python create new object, and might have some impact on memory usage.

Instead I'd use:

```
for index in xrange(400, 501):
    doSomething(allElements[index])
```

This way also enables you to manipulate list indexes during iteration.

EDIT: In Python 3.0 you can use `range()` instead of `xrange()`, but in 2.5 and earlier versions `range()` creates a list while `xrange()` creates a generator, which eats less of your precious RAM.